# JScroll: Change nextHref after ajax changed tab and URI

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-jscroll

JScroll can't see when the javascript changed window history with `pushState`.

I added JScroll for posts on index page. The default URL is *localhost* for example. And when there is no path after, the default posts will be loaded and jscroll will work as it should have.

But I have tabs on index page (new, top, hot), which change order of posts. So when I click on a tab, it dynamically changes URL with `window.history.pushState`, and sends request with new filter for showing posts.

But in JScroll, it still leaves old href and loads old data. For example - I am scrolling on *localhost/new*, and when I change tab to *localhost/top* in JScroll `nextHref` is `"http://localhost:8000/new?page=3 div.infinite-scroll"` instead of `"http://localhost:8000/top?page=1 div.infinite-scroll"`.

How can I change it so it is synced with tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

After each change of tab I added
`$('.infinite-scroll').removeData('jscroll').jscroll.destroy();`
and called JScroll initializer again.